# Android create global variable which holds its state

Tags: java, android, kotlin, class, global

I have an application in that whenever the internet connectivity changes , I need to make some variables in another activities unclickable.
Since internet connectivity might change in the first activity , hence the 2nd activity wont have any idea if the internet connectivity is there or not .

I need a way to create a global variable or a class which holds this status , So that all the activity can get the variable value and handle responses accordingly .

My initial idea was to create a base activity and make another activities inherit it.
But since that is a bad use of inheritence , I am searching for some other solutions.

Is there anything like that build in inside android or kotlin , Except for sharedPreferences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the singleton pattern. In Kotlin it's super easy:

```
object InternetConnectivityState {
  val connected: Boolean = false
}
```

And then you just update and read from the singleton object and it will be shared globally within your app process. For example:

```
myButton.enabled = InternetConnectivityState.connected
```

Comment: Ohh okaay got it thanks a lot . I am gonna use it for now , although I have heard from many places that the singleton pattern is some kind of devil and should be avoided at all costs. If in that case , is there any other way to handle my situation ?

Comment: IMO singletons get a bad rep because they tend to be overused, but there are cases where they would be appropriate. Alternatives depend on what properties of singleton you are trying to get away from – a common one is to move to a dependency injection framework like Dagger/Hilt, so you can replace the singleton during testing to avoid interference between tests or mock the connectivity state.

Answer (score 1):

You can store global variables

- in specially declared `object` singletons, just like Maurice mentioned
- in [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)
- in variables declared ouside of any class.

Of course, it's your choice if it's good practice. Dogma that 'singleton is bad' is not useful without understanding, why is it ))